# Visual Studio Error list is not refreshing before debug

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, refresh, error-list

in visual studio , when I wrote something wrong, error list is not refreshing, and there is no error until project starts (debug).

can you help me with this problem?

example:

```
private void SQL_sEinschlag()
        {

        }
```

**safsafavxyv**            (this must be an eror because meaningless and out of the method) until i start the project i cant see this error in the error list.

Comment: Does clicking on another part of the screen fix the problem? Sometimes the IDE will not visualize as you are "Focused" on the newly written code. Which would be very annoying.

Comment: No. But I solve the problem by just changing erorrlist filter as : **Nur Intelisense**  . Now it shows the failures immediately but it has 2 extra error messajage.                            1) 
Fehler  Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Java Development Kit. Please install it or set Java Development Kit path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu.    0   
2)
Fehler  Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. Please install it or set Android SDK path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu.    0.  I couldnt find a better solution for now.